# .Net 8 Blazor (Server and Client in auto mode) JSInterop isolation not finding js function

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0, blazor-jsinterop

I'm trying to get jsinterop to work in my .NET 8 Blazor application using both Client and Server.  I'm having a heck of a time figuring out what is wrong.  Sometimes it works, but as soon as I navigate to a new page, interop breaks.

I have all my JS files at the bottom of my Layout like so:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>

<!-- ########## External libraries below this line ##########-->

<!-- sidebar JS -->
<script src="/assets/js/defaultmenu.js"></script>

<!-- Notifications JS -->
<script src="/scripts/vendor/awesomenotifications/index.var.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/notifications.js"></script>
```

The two actions I am trying to do involve a large js function that slides the sidebar open or closed and the other is to show an error toast using awesome-notifications.

The js in defaultmenu.js is like this:

```
function toggleSidemenu() {
// many lines of code to do the slide and animations
}
```

The js in notifications,js looks like this:

```
function showErrorToast(message) {
    new AWN({}).alert(message);
}
```

I've tried adding the functions to window.  I've tried using export.  No matter what I do, I get the following error in my UI:

> Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'showErrorToast' ('showErrorToast' was undefined).
> Error: Could not find 'showErrorToast' ('showErrorToast' was undefined).

So, now onto my code.  I wanted to wrap the interop call into a service that could be used by injecting it into a component.  Here's roughly how that looks (exists in separate project but called from component in client project):

```
public class NotificationsJsInteropService(IJSRuntime js) : INotificationsInteropService
{
    public async Task ShowSuccessToastAsync(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            await using var module = await LoadNotificationsJs();

            await module.InvokeVoidAsync("showSuccessToast", message);
        }
        catch (JSDisconnectedException ex)
        {
            // Ignore
        }
    }

    public async Task ShowWarningToastAsync(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            await using var module = await LoadNotificationsJs();

            await module.InvokeVoidAsync("showWarningToast", message);
        }
        catch (JSDisconnectedException ex)
        {
            // Ignore
        }
    }

    public async Task ShowErrorToastAsync(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            await using var module = await LoadNotificationsJs();

            await module.InvokeVoidAsync("showErrorToast", message);
        }
        catch (JSDisconnectedException ex)
        {
            // Ignore
        }
    }

    private ValueTask<IJSObjectReference> LoadNotificationsJs()
    {
        return js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/scripts/vendor/awesomenotifications/index.var.js", "/assets/js/notifications.js");
    }
}
```

The code above is attempting to use interop isolation.  I cannot, no matter what I try, get interop to work for my application.  I have tried:

- moving the function into the layout at the end of the body and assigning it into window
- assigning the function to a variable
- loading the js files in the body
- only loading the notifications.js in the isolation code and the awesome-notifications package in the body

And here is my usage of the service (in client project):

```
public abstract class MyBasePage : AuthedBasePage
{
    [Inject]
    public INotificationsInteropService InteropService { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public IStateContainer<MyModel> StateContainer { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public IMyModelService MyModelService{ get; set; }

    protected MyModel Model { get; set; } = new();

    private bool ErrorOnDataLoad { get; set; }

    protected async Task LoadDataAsync()
    {
        StateContainer.OnStateChange += DataStateHasChangedAsync;
        StateContainer.OnInitialized += DataStateHasChangedAsync;

        await StateContainer.GetOrInitializeValueAsync(LoadDataFromApiAsync);
    }

    private Task DataStateHasChangedAsync(MyModel ? arg)
    {
        Model = arg;

        StateHasChanged();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task<MyModel> LoadDataFromApiAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            return await MyModelService.GetModelAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorOnDataLoad = true;
            return new MyModel();
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (ErrorOnDataLoad)
        {
            await InteropService.ShowErrorToastAsync("Error while retrieving intake form");
        }
    }
}
```

If the data fails to load, I'm setting a flag so I can make sure I only call the interop after render (as I've seen in most of the examples).

The other interop function I'm using is being called directly from a component on click (in client project):

```
public partial class NavigationToggleComponent
{
    [Inject] public IJSRuntime Js { get; set; }

    public async Task ToggleSidebar()
    {
        await Js.InvokeVoidAsync("toggleSidemenu");

        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

If I reload the page, this call works and the sidebar will open and close.  As soon as I use any navigation through the site, this interop call breaks.  The first shown interop can only be accessed after navigation has happened, so that is why I think my navigation might be breaking something.

Here is App.razor (in server project):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" data-nav-layout="vertical" class="light" data-header-styles="light" data-menu-styles="dark">

    <head>
        <base href="/">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="icon" type="/image/png" href="favicon.png">

        <HeadOutlet />
        
        <!-- fontawesome JS -->
        <script src="/scripts/fontawesome-6.5.1-pro.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Tailwind css -->
        <link href="/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <Routes />
    
</html>
```

The reason it looks like this is I have two completely different layouts (one for unauthenticated users and another after auth) for my site that involve different attributes on `<body>`

And Routes.razor (in server project):

```
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Client._Imports).Assembly }">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>
```

Here is my MainLayout (in client project):

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<HeadContent>
    <!-- Main JS -->
    <script src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>

    <!-- Style Css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">

</HeadContent>

<body class="">

<!-- page template omitted for brevity  -->

<div class="main-content">
    @Body
</div>

<!-- page template omitted for brevity  -->

<!-- blazor app -->
<script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>

<!-- External js libraries below this line -->

</body>
```

And just for clarity, here's what a nav item looks like that seems to break interop (in client project):

```
<li class="@ActiveClass("slide")">
    <NavLink href="@Url" class="side-menu__item navigation-item">@Text</NavLink>
</li>
```

EDIT

I found another post suggesting a module export was expected.  This is what I changed notifications.js to and STILL get an error that it cannot find showErrorToast

```
export function showSuccessToast(message) {
    new AWN({}).success(message);
}

export function showWarningToast(message) {
    new AWN({}).warning(message);
}

export function showErrorToast(message) {
    new AWN({}).alert(message);
}
    
export function showConfirm(message) {
    new AWN({}).confirm(message);
}
export function showInformation(message) {
    new AWN({}).info(message);
}
```

Comment: How well acquainted are you with Auto mode with interactivity set on page/component?  There's a lot of complexity to deal with.  `Routes` and `Layout` are rendering statically and every navigation is a round trip to the server.  There are three service containers to deal with.  Can you come up with a simpler [MRE] to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @Shaun your comment got me thinking and so I did some rearranging and rework of my layouts so that all the js declarations at the end of the body are now in the App.razor, and I removed the interactive auto from my layouts and moved it to be declared at page level.  That fixed all of my issues and now interop works in both instances in my question.

Comment: Excellent.  I'm glad you took my comments in the spirit they were intended.